# How do I replace everything(whitespaces/symbols) except letters and numbers in a JavaScript String?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to replace every single symbol and whitespace with the minus(-) sign in a string. I am not yet particularly familiar with Regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**negated character set**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

If you're okay keeping the underscore, you can use:

```
str.replace(/[^\w]/g, "-") // \w is the same as [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

If you want to replace that as well, then you can use:

```
str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, "-")
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by @JamesBuck, there are actually [negated shorthands](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html): `[^\w]` is the same as `\W`, so if you don't need to replace the underscore, you can use that, resulting in:

```
str.replace(/\W/g, "-")
```

Comment: Or just `\W` for the negated `\w`

Comment: @JamesBuck Good catch.

Comment: Perfect. I needed the second one, to replace the underscores as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: @timolawl Do you also know how to add the - sign in front of a upper case letter in a string? For example if I have thisIsALie the output should be this-is-a-lie after I turn the returned string to a lower case.

Comment: @tata `str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(x) { return '-' + x.toLowerCase(); })`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "djdkasfh da@S@FA";
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-');
```

Outputs `djdkasfh-da-S-FA`.